# How to highlight "prettified" symbols?

Tags: highlighting, prettify-symbols-mode

I would like to highlight where `prettify-symbols-mode` has prettified a symbol. For example, if Emacs displays `lambda` as `λ` it could be displayed with a gray background, but if a literal `λ` occurs in the text, the background would remain white.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could add another matcher using the same regexp as `prettify-symbols-mode`, i.e. something like this:

```el
(font-lock-add-keywords
 nil
 `((,(regexp-opt (mapcar 'car prettify-symbols-alist) t)
    (0 (when (funcall prettify-symbols-compose-predicate
                      (match-beginning 0)
                      (match-end 0)
                      (match-string 0))
         '(:background "grey80"))
       append)))
 'append)
```

Comment: This works, but when `prettify-symbols-unprettify-at-point` is `t` this also highlights the replaced string when cursor is at the prettified symbol. Is that a way to hightlight only the prettified symbol but not its original string? The reason is that I'm trying to use a face with a different font that has a symbol for the prettified symbol, but not for the original replaced characters.